# parse json information in google script with no recurring first tag

Tags: json, parsing, google-apps-script, tags

In google sheet, I've got a script to retrieve JSon from an url

```
function getTeamData() {
  var DATA_SPREADSHEET_ID = "xxxx";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(DATA_SPREADSHEET_ID);
  var TeamDataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("rawTeam");
  TeamDataSheet.clearContents();

  var url = 'xxxx';

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);

  var content = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(content);
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

The problem I've got is that the JSon content look like this

```
{
    "03wi4": {
        "statsIncId": 5546,
        "rotowireId": 3795,
        "name": "Saunders, Wesley",
        "fantraxId": "03wi4",
        "team": "NY",
        "position": "SG"
    },
    "059gh": {
        "statsIncId": 6321,
        "rotowireId": 4919,
        "name": "Booth, Phil",
        "fantraxId": "059gh",
        "team": "(N/A)",
        "position": "PG"
    },
    "02nfe": {
        "statsIncId": 5020,
        "rotowireId": 3308,
        "sportRadarId": "c555e067-c4d5-43f6-99af-716b6005cbba",
        "name": "Henson, John",
        "fantraxId": "02nfe",
        "team": "NY",
        "position": "PF"
    },
    "033b7": {
        "statsIncId": 5235,
        "rotowireId": 3538,
        "name": "Raduljica, Miroslav",
        "fantraxId": "033b7",
        "team": "(N/A)",
        "position": "C"
    },
...
}
```

I would like to be able to return the team for each of the entries but I don't have a common first tag name...
Could you please help, the result should look like this  :

````
059gh    (N/A)
02nfe    NY
033b7    (N/A)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to iterate and [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) :

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/ 
const json = {
"03wi4": {
    "statsIncId": 5546,
    "rotowireId": 3795,
    "name": "Saunders, Wesley",
    "fantraxId": "03wi4",
    "team": "NY",
    "position": "SG"
},
"059gh": {
    "statsIncId": 6321,
    "rotowireId": 4919,
    "name": "Booth, Phil",
    "fantraxId": "059gh",
    "team": "(N/A)",
    "position": "PG"
},
"02nfe": {
    "statsIncId": 5020,
    "rotowireId": 3308,
    "sportRadarId": "c555e067-c4d5-43f6-99af-716b6005cbba",
    "name": "Henson, John",
    "fantraxId": "02nfe",
    "team": "NY",
    "position": "PF"
},
"033b7": {
    "statsIncId": 5235,
    "rotowireId": 3538,
    "name": "Raduljica, Miroslav",
    "fantraxId": "033b7",
    "team": "(N/A)",
    "position": "C"
},
}
const values = Object.keys(json).map(k => [/*prepend ' for maintaining text format in sheets*/"'"+k, json[k].team])
console.table(values)
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```